# Laravel - how to select items by calculated deadline date

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My model has a "deadline" date which is *15 days after it's creation date.*

So I'm trying to select items by filtering this date.

```
<select name="deadline">
  <option value="">any</option>
  <option value="10">less than 10 days</option>
  <option value="6" >less than 6 days</option>
  <option value="3" >less than 3 days</option>
  <option value="0" >delayed</option>
</select>
```

controller

```
$deadline_total_days  = 15;
$filter_deadline_days = request()->get('deadline');

$q->whereDate('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()
                                    ->addDays($filter_deadline_days)
                                    ->subDays($deadline_total_days)
                                    );
...
```

This is not working. It always brings all items from database.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should probably pass a date string, not the entire `Carbon` object.

Comment: Add `->toDateString()`

Answer (score 0):

It was a logic problem, solved with:

```
$q->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(created_at, INTERVAL '.$deadline_total_days.' DAY), CURDATE()) <= '.$filter_deadline_days.' ');
```